# Randomly unable to access Angular library with npm link

Tags: angular, angular-library

I'm developing an Angular 16 library that I need to test within my main application. I use a basic setup:

- Watch + rebuild of the library when something changes
- `npm link` on the build folder
- `preserveSymlinks` set to true in the main app config

It works well enough overall but I regularly come across "XXXModule does not appear to be an NgModule class" when I modify the library. The full error is:

> XXXModule does not appear to be an NgModule class. This likely means that the library (XXX) which declares XXXModule is not compatible with Angular Ivy. Check if a newer version of the library is available, and update if so. Also consider checking with the library's authors to see if the library is expected to be compatible with Ivy.

I have to stop and restart everything (do a fresh build of the lib, restart the ng serve) which is annoying when it happens several times a day.

I have compared a "good" and a "bad" build,  and "bad" builds lack some lines so it seems that this isn't an issue with the `npm link` in the first place. It usually happens if I save files too quickly. Once I've had one of those "bad" builds my main app doesn't care about anything else, it will reload with the NgModule error even though the build has been fixed.

So I guess I have two questions:

- Is there an easier way to use the (in progress) library without relying on npm link?
- How can I solve the build issue without restarting everything? At this point, having to restart only the build would already be a nice improvement

**Edit**

A good build contains lines like these, that are missing in bad builds:

```
import * as i0 from "@angular/core";
import * as i1 from "@angular/cdk/dialog";
import * as i2 from "./layout/layout.module";
```

It seems like once a bad build happens, none of the builds after that will contain these missing lines. The only solution is to stop and restart the watch + build, which will remove and recreate the whole folder => it causes issues with the symlink for whatever reason and the server won't notice the changes until I restart it.

Answer (score 0):

When changes trigger a rebuild, your library will be deleted before the new one appears. On the other side, projects that consume your linked library will notice this and may crash. To avoid this issue, you need to add the following to the end of your angular.json file (for libraries).

```
  "defaults": {
    "build": {
      "deleteOutputPath": false
    }
  }
```

Comment: for success changes it works good, but if you will get compilations error you should do "serve" restart for project again